# List of core classes available by php5+?

Tags: php

Are there any other classes provided by php5+ such as the mysqli() class?

for example, I use this class to connect to the mysql database. Are there any other classes provided by php?

`$db = new mysqli('localhost','username','','mysql');`

Comment: For PHP, PDO is definitely the way to go. I'd recommend using an ORM too, such as Propel or Doctrine - and quite a few frameworks have their own data layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For database connections there is [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) available